# Mathematical bias and weight vs machine learning bias and weight

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, predictive-models, bias, weighted-mean

I am a little confused about the term Bias and Weight with respect to machine learning.

Say we want to predict the heights of people whose weights are given. So plot weights to x-axis and height to yaxis. To find out the linear relationship between height and weight we draw a straight line that shows the relationship between height and weight.

[image]

Using the equation for a line, you could write down this relationship

$y= mx+b ...i)$ more specifically in the machine learning terminology it could be $y= b+ w_1x_1...ii)$

So here b is the bias as per machine learning. However, b is the y-intercept as per mathematics. By defination b can be defined in machine learning `A value indicating how far apart the average of predictions is from the average of labels in the dataset.` Is that mean bias(b) is the distance between some particular point of the red line(as per picture) to the true point(say a blue or green point).

Now another confusion if this is the case then what is loss? As per defination loss is `A measure of how far a model's predictions are from its label.` Then what is the difference between loss and bias?

Now, for weight, here, weight(m)means slope as per equation i). Mathematically slope can be define as

$m = \frac{rise}{run} =\frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}$

However, weight$(w_1)$ can be defined in machine learning as `A coefficient for a feature in a linear model`. So my confusion is that is the procedure of finding weight is same as finding slope in mathematics?